# How to get width of a truetype font character in 1200ths of an inch with Python?

Tags: python, truetype

I can get the height and width of a character in pixels with PIL (see below), but (unless I'm mistaken) pixel size depends on the screen's DPI, which can vary. Instead what I'd like to do is calculate the width of a character in absolute units like inches, or 1200ths of an inch ("wordperfect units").

```
>>> # Getting pixels width with PIL
>>> font = ImageFont.truetype('/blah/Fonts/times.ttf' , 12)
>>> font.getsize('a')
(5, 14)
```

My reason for wanting to do this is to create a word-wrapping function for writing binary Word Perfect documents. Word Perfect requires soft linebreak codes to be inserted at valid points throughout the text, or the file will be corrupt and unopenable. The question is where to add them for variable width fonts.

I realize that I don't fully understand the relationship between pixels and screen resolution and font sizes. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: @teewuane I ultimately found a hack that forced Word Perfect to do the calculation itself (by replacing all spaces with soft line breaks)

Answer (score 12):

Raw text widths are usually calculated in [typographer's points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), but since the point for the purpose of font definitions is defined as 1/72 of an inch, you can easily convert it into any other unit.

To get the *design width* of a character (expressed in *em* units), you need access to the low-level data of the font. The easiest way is to [`pip install fonttools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools), which has everything to work at the lowest possible level of font definitions.

With fontTools installed, you can:

1. load the font data – this requires the path to the actual font file;
2. character widths are stored as *glyph* widths, meaning you must retrieve a 'character-to-glyph' mapping; this is in the `cmap` table of a font:

   a. load the `cmap` for your font. The most useful is the Unicode map – a font may contain others.
   b. load the *glyph set* for your font. This is a list of *names* for the glyphs in that font.
3. Then, for each Unicode character, first look up its name and then use the name to retrieve its width in design units.
4. Don't forget that the 'design units' is based on the overall 'design width' of a font. This can be a standard value of `1000` (typical for Type 1 fonts), `2048` (typical for TrueType fonts), or any other value.

That leads to this function:

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.ttLib.tables._c_m_a_p import CmapSubtable

font = TTFont('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf')
cmap = font['cmap']
t = cmap.getcmap(3,1).cmap
s = font.getGlyphSet()
units_per_em = font['head'].unitsPerEm

def getTextWidth(text,pointSize):
    total = 0
    for c in text:
        if ord(c) in t and t[ord(c)] in s:
            total += s[t[ord(c)]].width
        else:
            total += s['.notdef'].width
    total = total*float(pointSize)/units_per_em;
    return total

text = 'This is a test'

width = getTextWidth(text,12)

print ('Text: "%s"' % text)
print ('Width in points: %f' % width)
print ('Width in inches: %f' % (width/72))
print ('Width in cm: %f' % (width*2.54/72))
print ('Width in WP Units: %f' % (width*1200/72))
```

The result is:

```
Text: "This is a test"
Width in points: 67.353516
Width in inches: 0.935465
Width in cm: 2.376082
Width in WP Units: 1122.558594
```

and is correct when comparing to what Adobe InDesign reports. (Note that per-character *kerning* is not applied here! That would require a lot more code.)

Characters that are not defined in the font are silently ignored and, as usually is done, the width for the `.notdef` glyph gets used. If you want this reported as an error, remove the `if` test in the function.

The cast to `float` in the function `getTextWidth`  is so this works under both Python 2.7 and 3.5, but note that if you use Python 2.7 and larger value Unicode characters (not plain ASCII), you need to rewrite the function to correctly use UTF8 characters.

Comment: It always gives the same size, regardless the unicode character (arabic, chinese...).

Comment: @viyps: then you are using it wrong, in one of the following ways: (1) you selected a font which does not have glyphs for "arabic, chinese" and so you always get the `.notdef` width, or (2) you managed to pick individual characters that indeed have the exact same width, or (3) you picked a monospace font and so they are supposed to be the same width. (My bet is on (1).)

Comment: None of them, unfortunately. Arabic doesn't stay within the width even for monospace. At least, that was my experience with DejaVuSansMono. This method worked better for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781469/converting-text-to-image-with-unicode-characters

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```
def pixel_width(unicode_text): 
    width=len(unicode_text)*50 
    height=100 
    back_ground_color=(0,0,0) 
    font_size=64 
    font_color=(255,255,255) 

    im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color ) 
    draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw (im) 
    unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("./usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", font_size) 
    draw.text ( (0,0), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color ) 
    im.save("/dev/shm/text.png") 
    box = Image.open("/dev/shm/text.png").getbbox() 
    return box[2] - box[0]
```