# Autofit column width to text using Python for excel files independent of character count

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I am searching for a while and I found no straight forward answer to do so except using xlwings, which needs to use microsoft excel which is not desired in my case...

Only way to autofit column width to text is below code

```
for col in sheet.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = col[0].column_letter  # Get the column name
    for cell in col:
        if cell.coordinate in sheet.merged_cells:  # not check merge_cells
            continue
        try:  # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(str(cell.value))
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = max_length + 2
    sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

which is off course character count dependent...

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this, except to use Excel or a library that depends on it. That's just the way it is.

Comment: I assume there should be a way to get the character's width or whole string width instead of count based on fonts(probably from font file), what say?

Comment: There really isn't a reliable way AFAIK, sorry.

Comment: I think I have found a work around and will post it if it works as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code doesn't impact the performance significantly, but you need to have your font file and it's location for this code.

But still xlwings' way is more reliable

It is based on [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357457/13252809)

function for getting the width

```
def get_text_width(text_input, point_size):
    font = TTFont('../fonts/calibri_regular.ttf')
    cmap = font['cmap']
    t = cmap.getcmap(3, 1).cmap
    s = font.getGlyphSet()
    units_per_em = font['head'].unitsPerEm
    total = 0
    for c in text_input:
        if ord(c) in t and t[ord(c)] in s:
            total += s[t[ord(c)]].width
        else:
            total += s['.notdef'].width
    total = total * float(point_size) / units_per_em
    # getFont size in pixels
    inPix = (16 * total) / 12
    inOpenPyXlUnit = inPix / 7

    return inOpenPyXlUnit
```

And then Iterate and adjust column width...

```
for col in sheet.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = col[0].column_letter  # Get the column name
    longestTextCell = None
    for cell in col:
        if cell.coordinate in sheet.merged_cells:  # not check merge_cells
            continue
        try:  # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(str(cell.value))
                longestTextCell = cell
                # cell.font = mStyle
                # cell.font = mStyle
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = ((get_text_width(str(longestTextCell.value), 12)) + 2)
    print(column + " max width is " + str(adjusted_width))
    sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```